# Storing multi line html encoded string into sql

Tags: javascript, sql

I want to store html code into sql database which I've encoded by using `encodeURI()` but it showing me multiple errors as below

[image: error while inserting encoded html code]

I'm using dataType as `<CLOB>` also tried using `NVARCHAR(MAX)` but is showing same error.

Sharing my encoded html code below in string format tobe store into sql.

```
%3Cp%3Ethis%20kind%20of%20text%20i'm%20storing%20into%20database%3C/p%3E%3Cpre%20class=%22code-pre%22%3Evar uri%20= %22my%20test.asp?name=st%C3%A5le&car=saab%22;%0Avar enc%20=%20encodeURI(uri);%0Avar dec%20=%20decodeURI(enc);%0Avar res%20=%20enc%20+ %22<br>%22 +%20dec;%0A%3C/pre%3E

INSERT INTO "Mytable" VALUES(
8/*ID <INTEGER>*/,
'Return matching objects from array of objects'/*QUESTION <NVARCHAR(200)>*/,
'%3Cp%3Ethis%20kind%20of%20text%20i'm%20storing%20into%20database%3C/p%3E%3C     pre%20class=%22code-pre%22%3Evar uri%20= %22my%20test.asp ? 
 name=st%C3%A5le&car=saab%22;%0Avar enc%20=%20encodeURI(uri);%0Avar 
 dec%20=%20decodeURI(enc);%0Avar res%20=%20enc%20+ %22<br>%22 
 +%20dec;%0A%3C/pre%3E'/*QUESTION_DESC <CLOB>*/,
'20170508'/*CREATED <TIMESTAMP>*/,
0/*USERID <INTEGER>*/,
1/*TAGID <INTEGER>*/
);
```

Above command i'm using for pushing data to db. `QUESTION_DESC` string i've encoded.original string is

```
<p>this kind of text i'm storing into database</p><pre class="code- 
pre">var&nbsp;uri =&nbsp;"my test.asp?name=ståle&amp;car=saab";
var&nbsp;enc = encodeURI(uri);
var&nbsp;dec = decodeURI(enc);
var&nbsp;res = enc +&nbsp;"&lt;br&gt;"&nbsp;+ dec;
</pre>
```

Help will be appriciated

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: @Ovoxo i've edited the question

Comment: How are you actually trying to send the text to sql? I am hoping you are passing it in as a parameter rather than using string concatenation for the sql command? Showing the sql construction piece of your code may help to determine the issue.

Comment: @DavidShorthose i haven't wrote any middle ware code till now. but what type of string i'll be sending from front end which is html code with some indentation,css class and my database structure format i've shared.  I think this is enough explanatory. I just want to store that Html code into database.

Comment: I've sent encoded html back sql multiple times and this issue is usually down to how you are setting up your back end code to handle it. If you are constructing the code insert code like var sqlcommand = "insert into mytable values(8, '" + mytextfromfrontend + "',....)" then this is where your problem will be as any random apostrophes will be breaking the sql construction.

Comment: Could you provide the way in which format should i insert that data? so that those inverted comma's won't affect my insertion ? I do understand it is because of some apostrophes i'm facing that issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was quite simple when i tried posting html code from middle ware.
The problem is when i tried to post an html code to database it was showing error because of some random double quotes. So while sending that html code from middle ware i just replaced the double quotes to ignore double quotes. i did like

my html code to be stored in db

```
var htmlCodeToBeStored = 
"<p>this kind of text i'm storing into database</p><pre class="code- 
 pre">var&nbsp;uri =&nbsp;"my test.asp?name=ståle&amp;car=saab"; 
 var&nbsp;enc = encodeURI(uri);
 var&nbsp;dec = decodeURI(enc); 
 var&nbsp;res = enc +&nbsp;"&lt;br&gt;"&nbsp;+ dec;
 </pre>"
```

I replaced above string with as below
`htmlCodeToBeStored = htmlCodeToBeStored.replace(/"/g, "\"")`

with that simple change i'm able to store my ans into data base.